# setFrame:CGRectOffset behaviour is not consistent in iOS7 & 8

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using the following:

```
const int movementDistance = textField.frame.origin.y;
const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];

[scrollView setFrame:CGRectOffset(scrollView.frame, 0, movement)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

to scroll up the view when the keyboard covers up text fields.

However, I've noticed that in iOS 8 it doesn't work at all, but works okay in iOS7.

[image: iOS 7 scrolling]

[image: iOS 8 scrolling]

Comment: Animations in iOS8 no longer cancel previous animations on the same properties. This may be what's happening to you here. Try using `[scrollView.layer removeAllAnimations]` before starting your new animation block.

Comment: @IanMacDonald no effect/change.